# crack pdf using python scrypt

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

i have to write a scrypt (for  a university class and i must send to proffesor until sunday) that will crack a pdf file, i have tryied a lot so far but cant make it work my code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import logging
import time

t=time.localtime()

t1=time.asctime(t)
log_filename='pass_found.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_filename,level=logging.INFO)
output = PdfFileWriter()
pdf = PdfFileReader(file( "sf.pdf", "rb"))
f=open('datepass.txt')   
content=f.readlines()
words=[x.strip() for x in content]
  for i in words:
       if (pdf.decrypt(i) == 1) or (pdf.decrypt(i) == 2):
             logging.info('{0} :o kodikos einai "{1}"'.format(t1,i))
```

datepass is a txt that contains date passwords(DD-MM-YY-> date-month-year)

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'crack a pdf'? What information do you want to extract. What errors do you see when you try and run the above code?

Comment: i dont have errors it doesnt work or return any i....

Comment: our prof said its password protected and we have to open it with a python scrypt. the form of the password is DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: Create a test case to see if your code works: a PDF with a known password (one in `datepass.txt`). If this works, your password is not in that file.

Comment: i have every date from 00-00-0000 to 31-12-2015

Comment: How do you know the password isn't any later than 31-12-2015? If you can go all the way back to 00-00-0000 (shouldn't that be 01-01-0000?) why not go up until 31-12-9999? Jongware had the best suggestion, though. Since we don't know what the real password is, your code may very will be working just fine. You need to create a test case for yourself where you know the password, and see if your code finds it.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python3
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf=PdfFileReader(file( "sf.pdf", "rb"))

f=open('datepass.txt')   
content=f.readlines()
words=[x.strip() for x in content]
for i in words:
   try:
         a=pdf.decrypt(i)
         if a==1:
            with open("datefound.txt", "w") as text_file:
                 text_file.write(i)
   except:
      pass